# Sun Keyboard type 7 doesn't copy

Tags: linux, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a Sun Keyboard Type 7:

[image]

and I cannot use the "copy", "paste", "cut" keys on the left on Linux Mint 17... they work on Firefox, but nowhere else.

Is there a way to make those keys work globally? (I already tried in "menu > settings > keyboard", but I can only make bindings to commands and not bind a key to a different key combinations, in this case, copy, paste or cut)

Maybe there is a driver, but I searched for quite a while without luck.

The computer can see the keys when they're pressed xinput list:

[image]

Comment: This might help:  http://superuser.com/questions/385748/binding-superc-superv-to-copy-and-paste?rq=1   The keys are different, but the idea is the same:  map copy/paste to single keys.

Comment: I tried creating '$home/copySun.xmodmap' with this content:

keycode 141 = XF86Copy
keycode 143 = XF86Paste

didn't work... then I tried with this content

keycode 141 = Control_L c
keycode 143 = Control_L v

and then running: ' xmodmap copySun.xmodmap ' each time without luck

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a current server setup where I could look into this - it's definitely something I've always wanted to get working.  Here's the bug fix for Firefox that enabled the keys, it might help also:  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665406  And this mentions the `XF86Copy`, `XF86Cut`, and `XF86Paste` keycodes and directly ties their use to Sun keyboards:  http://xahlee.info/linux/linux_xmodmap_tutorial.html

Answer (score 1):

In `GNOME 3 Tweaks` > `Keyboard` > `Additional Layout Options` > `Maintain key compatibility with old Solaris keycodes`, you should try checking off `Sun Key compatibility`.

As you are probably using GNOME 2 (did not specify in question), there should be an equivalent tool also available that does the same thing.